# Making circles appear and disappear with mouseenter and mouseleave in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a plot in d3.js, a scatter plot of small black dots where, if you hover over a small black dot, a new semi-transparent larger red dot appears in the same position and *in addition to* the original black dot, and when the mouse leaves the region of the original black dot, the red dot disappears.

I have what appear to be two problems. The first is that the red circle vanishes the instant that it is created. I know it is created because if I remove the `.on("mouseleave")` part (method?) then the red circle successfully appears, though of course then stays around.

The second problem is that, with the `.on("mouseleave")` part removed, when a red circle has appeared, none of the other black dots shadowed by that larger red circle will produced their own red circles.

I have tried using "mouseover" and "mouseout" instead of "mouseenter" and "mouseleave", with the same results. If anyone has any suggestions I'll much appreciate them. Thanks!

Here's the relevant code. Happy to post more if requested but wanted to draw focus to the important part.

```
drawdots = function() {
    sg.selectAll("circle")
        .remove();
    sg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(df)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale(Math.log(d.x)/Math.log(10));})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale(Math.log(d.y)/Math.log(10));})
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) {return "point" + i})
        .attr("r", 5)
        .on("mouseenter", function(d, i) {
            var cx = sg.select("#point" + i)
                        .attr("cx");
            var cy = sg.select("#point" + i)
                        .attr("cy");
            sg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", cx)
                .attr("cy", cy)
                .attr("r", 20)
                .attr("fill", "red")
                .attr("opacity", 0.5)
                .attr("id", "red_circle" + i);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function(d, i) {
            sg.select("#red_circle" + i)
                .remove();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this in a different way -- instead of having one red dot, draw one for each black one and only show on mouseover. This would siplify the code, which would basically look like this.

```
sg.selectAll("circle.black")
    .data(df)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "black")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale(Math.log(d.x)/Math.log(10));})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale(Math.log(d.y)/Math.log(10));})
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {return "point" + i})
    .attr("r", 5);

sg.selectAll("circle.red")
    .data(df)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "red")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale(Math.log(d.x)/Math.log(10));})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale(Math.log(d.y)/Math.log(10));})
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {return "red_circle" + i})
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .on("mouseenter", function() { d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.5); })
    .on("mouseleave", function() { d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0); });
```

Comment: Thanks, Lars. What I'm looking for eventually is to have the red circle appear by transitioning from radius r=0 to radius r=20. I think this would rule out using mouseenter on the red circle itself, since it would start out with no area. If not for that, I would agree that your approach is preferable.

Comment: I see. You might want to create a `g` element in that case that holds the circles and has the events attached to it. The reason that your current approach doesn't work is that as soon as you create the new circle, your mouse is not on the old one anymore (as the new one overlaps it) and the even to remove it is triggered. Same thing for the second problem you've mentioned.

Comment: Actually, something like the approach you first suggested might work. However, how do I get the red circles to show up? Without specifying keys to data() the black circles take up the default indices so seemingly a key function must be passed to data() the second time around. However, when I pass `data(df, function (d, i) { return i + df.length })` for the second `data`, I still don't see the red circles. (Brand new to d3.js and JavaScript, so I may be missing something super obvious.)

Comment: The easiest is probably to simply use different classes and the appropriate selectors as in the code I've posted.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the different classes. I think this is the right way to go; thanks!